# drawing float in pygame blit

Tags: python, pygame

I have a problem with:

```
screen.blit(tile, [(x*tilewidth) - CAMERA.x +(WIDTH/2) , (y*tileheight) - CAMERA.y + (HEIGHT/2)])

screen.blit(object.image, [object.x - CAMERA.x +(WIDTH/2), object.y - CAMERA.y + (HEIGHT/2)])
```

The code above generates an error:

```
DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float).  Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated and may be removed in a future version of Python.
  screen.blit(tile, [(x*tilewidth) - CAMERA.x +(WIDTH/2) , (y*tileheight) - CAMERA.y + (HEIGHT/2)])
```

The program starts but then crashes due to an error. How do I fix this?

Comment: `WIDTH/2` results in a float. Try integer division: `WIDTH // 2`

Comment: without result still the same

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Comment: yes, you help me

Answer (score 3):

[`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) the cooridantes to integral values:

<s>`screen.blit(tile, [(x*tilewidth) - CAMERA.x +(WIDTH/2) , (y*tileheight) - CAMERA.y + (HEIGHT/2)])`</s>

```py
screen.blit(tile, 
    [round(x*tilewidth - CAMERA.x + WIDTH/2), round(y*tileheight - CAMERA.y + HEIGHT/2)])
```

or use the `//` (floor division) operator (this only works if all the variables have integral values):

```py
screen.blit(tile, 
    [x*tilewidth - CAMERA.x + WIDTH//2, y*tileheight - CAMERA.y + HEIGHT//2])
```